# If $(\forall x,y\in \Bbb R)(f(x+f(y)) = f(x) +y)$ and $f(0) =1$, then $f(7) = ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem :

If $(\forall x,y\in \Bbb R)(f(x+f(y)) = f(x) +y)$ and $f(0) =1$, then $f(7) = ?$

Please guide how to handle such problem I have no clue how to proceed ,, thanks..

Comment: In fact none now, @GitGud, since the OP apparently used logic notation and after the quantificator he included all the formula within parentheses...it really confused me. Thanks.

Comment: I see, @GitGud...well, if someone's not expecting that I think that can be confusing.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is impossible. Applying the formula with $x = y = 0$, you get
$$f(1) = f(0+f(0)) = f(0) + 0 = 1.$$
Similarly, by using this with $x = 1$, $y = 0$, you get
$$f(2) = f(1+f(0)) = f(1) + 0 = 1.$$
On the other hand, we could have used $x = 1$, $y = 1$ and obtained
$$f(2) = f(1+f(1)) = f(1) + 1 = 2,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Nicely done and caught. +1

Comment: but the answer given is 1?????

Comment: @sultan There is no solution. It's like asking what number $x$ is such that $x+1=x$, there is none (in ordinary real arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=0$ you obtain $f(x+1) = f(x)$ thus $f(7) = f(6) = ... = f(0) = 1$

But you can show that there is no such function f, so every 'solution' is a correct answer to your question.